# Using Different Ringtones In The Android App

Tags: android, flutter, android-notifications

I am developing an application using flutter programming in Visual Studio. In the application I developed, I want to divide the notifications into categories and play them with a different ringtone for each category. I connect any android device to my computer by opening developer options and turning on USB debugging. When I install the app on the device via USB, I can run different notification sounds, but when I download and install the app from the Google Play Store, the notification sounds do not work.

How can I solve this problem?

I want to use different ringtones as notification tones in the application I developed.

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
//import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await init();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

Future<void> init() async {
  PermissionStatus status = await Permission.notification.status;
  if (!status.isGranted) {
    status = await Permission.notification.request();
  }

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
 }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  // Method to initialize notification channels.
  Future<void> _initializeNotifications() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/launcher_icon');
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);

    // Define channel for alerts.
    const AndroidNotificationChannel alertChannel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
        'alert', // Kanal ID
        'Alert Channel', // Kanal Adı
        // 'Channel for important alerts', // Kanal Açıklaması
        importance: Importance.high,
        sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound("alert"));

    // Define channel for regular notifications.
    const AndroidNotificationChannel normalChannel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
        'noti', // Kanal ID
        'Normal Channel', // Kanal Adı
        //'Channel for normal notifications', // Kanal Açıklaması
        importance: Importance.high,
        sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound("noti"));

    // Create the channels.
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(alertChannel);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(normalChannel);

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      // Bildirim alındığında bu metot tetiklenecek
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;

      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        _showNotification(
          android.channelId ?? 'noti',
          notification.title ?? '',
          notification.body ?? '',
        );
      }
    });
  }

  // const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _initializeNotifications();
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      localizationsDelegates: const [GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate],
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('en')],
      home: const LoginPage(),
      builder: EasyLoading.init(),
    );
  }

  // Method to display notifications.
  Future<void> _showNotification(
      String channelID, String title, String body) async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      channelID,
      title,
      //'your_channel_description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );
    NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .show(0, title, body, platformChannelSpecifics, payload: 'item x');
  }
}
```